# Multibranch Pipeline - configure branch projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

When I create a plain pipeline project I have the option to periodically poll the scm and if changes are detected, the build is run. that worked well for me.

Now I created a multibranch pipeline and added 2 branches. However, in the configuration I can not set the same as in the normal pipeline project, because it tells me I can only view the configurations of the sub-branch-projects.

Maybe I'm also doing it wrong, so I try to tell you what I actually want to achieve.

I have a PHP project inside of a Git repository. There are two branches that I want to be built on new commits (when pushed to the main repository)
The main repository resides on a self hosted version of Bitbucket Server. If possible, I want to avoid hooks and let Jenkins poll for changes on the bitbucket server. So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

If I got you right, all you want to do is to build ONLY these 2 branches?

If so, under *"Branch Sources"* just click the "*Advanced*" and fill in the textfield "*Include branches*" your branches e.g. `test test2` (note the space between the branch names)

Comment: I want them to be built when changes were pushed.

Comment: Then you have to setup e.g. Stash to notify jenkins in case a commit was done. Add a Post-Receive Webhook in the form of http://jenkinsserver/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@yourgitserver/test.git

I also had to activate polling in order to activate the branch indexing automatically.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Even though this wasn't what this question was asking, you answered *my* question: I couldn't find any documentation as to the format of the 'Include branches' text.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Thanks a lot. I too was looking for documentation about "Include branches" format. You answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to check the option *Periodically if not otherwise run* trigger at the multibranch level. This replaces per-job polling, because it also detects new branches and the like.

Comment: I actually hunted around quite a bit for this answer.  "Periodically if not otherwise run" is under "build triggers", and i guess "build" to me doesn't mean poll the SCM for changes.  The configuration options were not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you'll have configure SCM pollig (the way you expect it) in the Jenkinsfile itself. It's the `properties` DSL elelement that handles the configuration:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H 20 * * 1-5')])
])
```

Anyways I highly suggest to have a closer look at the Pipeline Snippet Generator:

```
<your-jenkins-url>/pipeline-syntax/
```

it s easy to miss but extremely helpful and it s populated based on your currently installed plugins. There you will also find a comprehensible set of options available for `properties`